# HQL/JPQ using fetch for where section

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

in code like this

```
  @Query("select se.id from someEntity se"
  + " inner join se.anotherOne ao"
  + " inner join se.lazyOne l"
  + " where l.someField = true")
```

Should I use "fetch" to get someFiled from lazy entity or Hibernate/Jpa/Spring Data/God will do it for me?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary as you pose the query, you could do the following:

```
@Query("select se.id, ao.id, l.id from someEntity se"
+ " inner join se.anotherOne ao"
+ " inner join se.lazyOne l"
+ " where l.someField = true")
```

And indicate as the class returned when executing the query a pojo with a constructor that matches in order and type with the parameters of the select clause as follows:

```
public YourPojo(Long idSomeEntity, Long idAnotherOne, Long idLazyOne){
    //Object construction
}
```

The use of fetch would be for example if you wanted to bring you a list of someEntity entities with their lazyOne property fed

```
@Query("select se from someEntity se"
+ " join fetch se.anotherOne ao"
+ " join fetch se.lazyOne l"
+ " where l.someField = true")
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends. If you JOIN FETCH lazy field, hibernate won't run another query to fetch it later. Otherwise when accessing this field, hibernate will have to query database for it. It's more of optimization thing.